# OpenCV video playback: image not shown when reopening a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I ran into a strange problem using Python (3.8.6) Tkinter and OpenCV. I'm trying to play a video in a loop, until another video is selected.

When I open a video the first time, it starts playback normally. When I then open another video (same video or other video), the first video stops, but the image of the second video is not displayed (it seems to play in background). Strangely, it does display the video when the tkinter filedialog shows to open yet another video. But when the dialog is cancelled, the display stops again.

If I manually close the playback ('p') and reopen a video ('o') it works normally.
If the video is finished (without looping) before a new video is opened it also works normally.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

VIDEO_RATE = int(1000.0/30.0)

class VideoPlayback:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cv2Video = None

    def __del__(self):
        if self.cv2Video and self.cv2Video.isOpened():
            self.cv2Video.release()

    def openVideo(self, src, width=405, height=720):
        self.cv2Video = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        if not self.cv2Video.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", src)
        self.resizeDim = (width,height)

    def closeVideo(self):
        if self.cv2Video:
            self.cv2Video.release()

    def readVideoFrame(self, retry=5):
        if self.cv2Video and self.cv2Video.isOpened():
            ret, frame = self.cv2Video.read()
            if ret:
                return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(frame, self.resizeDim), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else:
                if retry:
                    self.cv2Video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
                    return self.readVideoFrame(retry=retry-1)
                else:
                    return (False, None)
        else:
            return (False, None)

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Minimal working example")

        self.geometry("1280x740+2+2")
        self.attributes("-fullscreen",True)

        frTop = tk.Frame(master=self, width=1280, height=720)
        frTop.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        # Playback canvas
        self.cnvVideo = tk.Canvas(master=frTop, width=405, height=720)
        self.cnvVideoImg = self.cnvVideo.create_image(0,0, anchor='nw')
        self.cnvVideo.pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=1)

        # Buttons
        self.bind("o",self.openVideoPlayback)
        self.bind("p",self.closeVideoPlayback)
        
        # reference video playback
        self.video = VideoPlayback()
        self.afterVideo = None

    def openVideoPlayback(self, *args):
        # show file dialog
        videoSrc = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = 'Open video', filetypes=(("Video files (*.mp4)","*.mp4"),("All files (*.*)","*.*")))
        if videoSrc:
            # open selected video for playback
            self.video.openVideo(videoSrc, width=405, height=720)
            # start update loop
            self.afterVideo = self.after(VIDEO_RATE, self.updateVideoPlayback)

    def updateVideoPlayback(self):
        (ret, frame) = self.video.readVideoFrame()
        if ret:
            image = Image.fromarray(frame)
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image, master=self)
            self.cnvVideo.itemconfig(self.cnvVideoImg, image=image)
            self.cnvVideo.image = image
            self.cnvVideo.after(VIDEO_RATE, self.updateVideoPlayback)
        else:
            print("Stop rescheduling")

    def closeVideoPlayback(self, *args):
        # stop video playback
        if self.video:
            self.video.closeVideo()

app = MainWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

I tried adding `self.video.closeVideo()`  before opening a new video.
I tried adding `self.after_cancel(self.afterVideo)` before opening a new video.

The code is part of a larger Tkinter interface, but stripped to minimal (non)working example.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Python 3.7 & OpenCV 4.4.0.42.

Comment: @HenryYik are you on Windows? My exact configuration is: Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 & OpenCV 4.4.0. I will try downgrading Python.

Comment: Problem persists with Python 3.7 (also in Python 2.7), so it seems unrelated to Python version. I fixed it by adding `self.cnvVideo.update_idletasks()` to updateVideoPlayback, but this seems only a work-around from my perspective.